# Is it okay to say "our meet up is pending"?

Tags: grammar

if you had a discussion with someone in past about meeting up and then never get a chance to meet or make a plan. What is the best way to tell them that our meeting is due?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say

> Our meet up is still on the table.
>
> Our meet up is still up for discussion.
>
> Our meet up is still an idea.

All of these refer to the meet up as not having a specific date and not being certain but still being something both of you want to do and might do.

If the meeting has a date/is definitely happening, you should say

> Our meet up is coming up **or** upcoming.
>
> Our meet up is in the plans.
>
> Our meet up is due.